# Select single column from dataset with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

Just getting my head around all this LINQ stuff and it seems I'm stuck at the first hurdle.

I have a datatable as such:

```
OrderNo     LetterGroup Filepath
----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
0           0           Letters/SampleImage.jpg
0           0           Letters/UKPC7_0.jpg
0           0           Letters/UKPC8_0.jpg
```

What I need is to get all of the filepaths from the Filepath column into a String array.  I thought LINQ would be perfect for this (am I right?), but can't seem to construct the correct query.

Can anyone provide some code samples that would point me in the right direction?  I have searched around - but don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are extension methods which make working with data sets much easier:

```
using System.Data.Linq;

var filePaths =
    from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    select row.Field<string>("Filepath");

var filePathsArray = filePaths.ToArray();
```

You can also use the method syntax to put it in one statement:

```
var filePaths = dataTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row.Field<string>("Filepath"))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Why am I getting 'dataTable does not contain a definition for "Field"'?

Comment: @Spero: That sounds like a missing extension method. Did you include this? `using System.Data.Linq;`

Comment: Thx for the response. I added the necessary assembly and include, but the error is still there. I am pulling the data from DbContext though, not DataSet. I dunno how to use DataSet in Linq yet.

Comment: I found this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738238/convert-dbcontext-to-datatable-in-code-first-entity-framework    Is this necessary?

Comment: It seems what I am looking for is closer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069154/how-can-i-select-just-two-columns-from-a-list-using-linq

Comment: @Spero: This answer only applies to usages of `DataSet`. If you are using `DbContext`, there will be ways to do this there. Don't convert your `DbContext` to `DataSet` just to use this answer.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. Tim Schmelter's answer in the other thread worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

```
string[] filePaths = (from DataRow row in yourDataTable.Rows 
                     select row["Filepath"].ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: This isn't using LINQ at all.

Comment: @poindexter12 - What?  Sure looks like LINQ to me.

Comment: @jfar: This is technically LINQ syntax, so I removed my down vote. However, in the spirit the question, I think there was a little more that could be explained.

Comment: @poindexter, the OP asked how to utilize LINQ to query his dataset, he did not ask how to completely revamp his data access strategy. This is certainly a classic use of LINQ-to-Objects. You would have him go to a LINQ-to-Entities (or equivalent) model.

Comment: I agree on all counts, I would have him go LINQ to Sql.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use LINQ all the way, set up your database and create a context object.  Then you should be able to do something like this:

```
 var filepaths = from order in _context.Orders
                 select order.Filepath;
```

This is assuming your table for the row is named Orders, which I guess by your first column name of order.  If you wanted to return a set of the order numbers as well for using later to know where the file path came from you could do something like so:

```
var results = from order in _context.Orders
              select new
              {
                  order.OrderNo,
                  order.Filepath
              }
```

This would give you a new anonymous type that contained both those values as properties.