# How can I select just two columns from a list using LINQ

Tags: c#

I have a variable that contains a list of the following Class:

```
public class Test
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
}
```

IList abc;

How can I create a new list that contains just the first two columns using LINQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list is not the problem but your class, it has three properties. So you either have to use an anonymous type or a `Tuple<int, int>`, change your class or create a new class with just two properties.

New class approach:

```
public class Test2
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
}

var list = testList
   .Select(t => new Test2{ a = t.a, b = t.b } )
   .ToList();
```

Anonymous type:

```
var list = testList
   .Select(t => new { a = t.a, b = t.b } )
   .ToList();
```

`List<Tuple<int, int>>` approach:

```
var list = testList
   .Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.a, t.b))
   .ToList();
```

Here is another approach that just takes two properties and leaves the third `int.MinValue`:

```
var list = testList
   .Select(t => new Test{ a = t.a, b = t.b, c = int.MinValue} )
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Test.Select(x => new { x.a, x.b }).ToList();
```

If you want to use the same List of Test, you need to provide default value to column c and include it.

```
const int defaultValue = 0;
List<Test> result = Test.Select(x => new { x.a, x.b, c = defaultValue }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a LINQ query that returns an anonymous type

```
var qRequest = from x in yourList
               select new { A = x.Field1, B = x.Field2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Test> tt =  new List <Test> () ;
tt.Select(x => new {x.a, x.b}).ToList () ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
List<Test> list = new List<Test>();
List newList = list.Select(i => new { i.a, i.b});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newLIst = from t in myTestList select new { a= t.a,b=t.b }.ToList();
```

This way the columns are still named the same for clarity.