# Convert DbContext to Datatable in Code first entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, datatable, dbcontext

Hello I am trying to convert `DbContext` result to `DataTable`. I have one `class` i.e. `ClientTemplateModel` which `inherits` `DbContext`. In this class I have one `DbSet` object i.e. 
`public virtual DbSet<imagecomment> ImageComments { get; set; }`.  I am using **Code first entity framework**.

Here is my query.

```
using (ClientTemplateModel context = new ClientTemplateModel(connectionString))
{
  var result = context.ImageComments.Where(p => p.Dcn == dcn).OrderByDescending(p => p.CommentsDateTime);
}
```

Here I am want convert the `result` into `DataTable`. How can I convert this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use Extension method that converts your Generic List To Datatable , you can use IQueryable/Ienumerable also instead of IList , follow the code

```
  public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = 
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                 row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

if you have not used extension method before please see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805044/1018054

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: Thank you for reply. How can call this?

Comment: I used the extension method but in my case how can call this method ?

Comment: you can create a static class and this method inside and then result.ToDatatable() , i hv given msdn ref. please look into that for more on this..

Comment: make sure your result is of type you specified in arguments of method.

Comment: I have change my method to static and tried this `var result = context.ImageComments.Where(p => p.Dcn == dcn).OrderByDescending(p => p.CommentsDateTime);
DataTable dt = result.ToDataTable;` But I could not find `.ToDataTable`