# entity generic dbSet get datatable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Is it possible to get `dataTable` from a generic `entity.DbSet` i have tried but the only way to get data that worked so far is the `Local` maybe i missed one but i tried parsing it like below 
 `DataSet ds = entityDbSet as DataSet;` but it's not possible. 
 The only way i am thinking of is putting the `entity.dbSet` in a list, basically looping it but i am sure it's not the best idea. 
i would try `tolistasync` but i didn't figure out yet how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interfaces are not compatible and you cannot not just cast them like that.

```
public class DbSet<TEntity> : DbQuery<TEntity>, IDbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IQueryable, IEnumerable, IInternalSetAdapter where TEntity : class

public class DataSet : MarshalByValueComponent, System.ComponentModel.IListSource, IXmlSerializable, ISupportInitializeNotification, ISerializable
```

What you can do and this will be very helpful for you:

```
var users = dbContext.Users.ToListAsync().Result.ToDataTable();

public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

[Convert DbContext to Datatable in Code first entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738238/convert-dbcontext-to-datatable-in-code-first-entity-framework)

To guarantee the asynchronous your method have to be async and the converting must done after the awaiting.