# How to Get Single Column Value in c# LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, asenumerable

```
DataTable Master_Table = Execute_Manager.getTableDataSet(connection, select_query, master_table);
string RuleName = (From EachRow in Master_Table
        where EachRow.Field<string>("RuleID") == "123456"
        Select EachRow.Field<string>("RuleName")).CopyToDataTable().ToString();
```

I need to get single Column Value using LINQ in Datatable c#

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select single column from dataset with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433366/select-single-column-from-dataset-with-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following I have added in the two examples below:

```
string carManufacturer = "BMW";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
int id = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
    where (string)dr["CarManufacturer"] == carManufacturer
    select (int)dr["id"]).FirstOrDefault();
```

```
string columnValue = dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

What column value are you trying to fetch from your data table?